How do I grant a service account permissions to the Google Analytics Admin API?
What is this doing? It creates a new project and a service account json key for me? How is it granting the service account access to the API?: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/quickstart-client-libraries#step_1_enable_the_api
I want to use an existing GCP project. I want to enable the Google Analytics Admin API and grant a service account access to use it, but I don't understand how to do this.
I can find no permission for the analytics admin API, just analytics hub:

How do I give a service account access to this API?
How do I give a Google service account access to the Google Analytics Admin API in a project?
Also, I manage my service accounts in a centralized project. How can I enabled the API in one project and access it with a service account from a different project? Is this not possible? Must I create the service account in the same project where the API is enabled? Otherwise I don't understand how I could give that GSA access to the API in a different project- as there are no IAM permissions I can find.

I suspect that Google Analytics is not supported by Cloud IAM. Once you've created the Service Account, you will need to add its email (${ACCOUNT}@${PROJECT}.iam.gserviceaccount.com to your Analytics profile. There's a note about this here

I don't want to use their setup tool how do I do this manually? How does a service account get access to the analytics admin api of a project?
